# Array of expiremental data filtering

Tags: matlab, math, filtering

I have a problem filtering an array with experimental data - the data is a long array(double). The index of this array is simply time (second) and the values could be negative or positive. The problem is that is sometimes experimental data is quite wrong(( - this is due to 
to errors in our device. This error values are very different from other array values. For example 
first 100 seconds values equals to +75 +(small delta value) or - 40 -(small delta value), but then, during 3 second value is +270 (this is an error I have spoken above). How to clean this values from array? The mean value counting perhaps not best way because if I take every value from array for sum this error data spoil the whole statistic (due to it large "weight"). I have plot  this data - the picture is clear but.. If this errors were caused by something like white noise then I could implement for example Kalman filter but there is firstly NO function for calculating the values and secondly this errors are NOT white noise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume we have right values most of the time. If signal is permanent (with small delta), we can use median to filter data:

```
delta = 1e-3;
a=[75 * ones(1,20) + rand(1,20) * delta, 270 * ones(1,3) + rand(1,3) * delta];
m = median(a);
filtered_a = a(m - 2 * delta < a & a < m + 2 * delta);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this solution is perfect for pre-defined data. But I don't know what values will be error for the next time. It could be 270, but if the next experimental results will have correct (common) values  270 +- delta and Bad values will be 2 +- delta or 1000 +- delta this approach will not work(

Comment: I rewrote the answer above.

Comment: could you answer one more question - if I have only 2 values of a array in every period of time  - present and next could I use a the median to get m value on them in filtered_a?

Comment: You need to have right values of data at least on half your array and it must be permanent.